# How to find the "timing advance" network parameter on a Symbian phone?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

How can I find the network parameter "timing advance" in a Symbian s60 phone.. Am developing the application with qt. i couldn't find a documentation about timing advance in it.

Comment: Did you find timing advance in any of the mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

I heard of the Nokia Netmonitor

[image]

that gives you the TA and other GSM parameters but it doesn't work on public phones anymore. I've been working on this project for a month and it seems timing advance cannot be retrieved by a mobile user anymore. Let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: @JeyanthKumar Do you find TA value in any of mobile app? It's really critical for us.